# custom EL function that takes no parameters - possible?

Tags: jsp, el

I created an EL function that takes no parameters:

```
<function>
  <name>noArg</name>
  <function-class>com.example.customtag.function.PrintHi</function-class>
  <function-signature>java.lang.String noArg()</function-signature>
</function>
```

I invoke it as follows in a jsp:

```
<c:set var="myvar2" value="${ mytags:noArg() }"/> 
<c:out value="${myvar2}"/>
```

This works and produces the desired output in my browser (just returns a string).  But Eclipse is telling me the above `<c:set...` is invalid.  Specifically at `mytags.noArg()`

So I am wondering if this is the correct way to implement a noarg EL function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely the correct way to implement such a function.

If it works, then don't worry about it. Eclipse's JSP validation is *far* from perfect.